# How to capture all the substrings inside a string that start with an element of a list and end with another element of another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

#input string
capture_where_capsule = "alrededor ((NOUN)del auto rojizo, algo grande y completamente veloz). Luego dentro del baúl rápidamente abajo de una caja por sobre ello vimos una caña."

#list of adverbs indicating the start of the capture
list_all_adverbs_of_place = ["adentro", "dentro", "al rededor", "alrededor", "abajo", "hacía", "hacia", "por sobre", "sobre"]

#It should cut everything in place_reference_string  after '((NOUN) )'
descriptive_noun_pattern = r"\(\(NOUN\)" + r'(?:[\w,;.]\s*)+' + r"\)"


list_verbs = ["vimos", "hemos visto", "encontramos", "hemos encontrado"]
list_adverbs_of_manner = ["rápidamente", "rapidamente", "intensamente", "gradualmente", "completamente"]
list_adverbs_of_time = ["durante", "luego", "ahora", "mientras tanto"]
list_limitant_words = ["a las", "a los", "a la", "a el", "a los", "a las", "a mí", "a mi", "a sus", "a su", "a él", "a ella", "talvez", "tal vez", "tal", "al", "los", "las", "él", "el", "la", "cómo", "como" , "con", "en su", "en mi", "en", ".", ":", ";", ",", "(", ")", "[", "]", "¿", "?", "¡", "!", "&", "="]

#list that combines all the elements that act as limits, indicating when the captures should end
list_limiting_elements = list_verbs + list_adverbs_of_manner + list_adverbs_of_time + list_limitant_words

print(repr(capture_where_capsule)) #--> output
```

I must capture within the encapsulation standard `((PL_ADVB)the text)` , those strings that are after one of the elements of the list `list_all_adverbs_of_place` , which basically consists of a small list of adverbs indicating place. (the adverb must also be captured).

And the end of the capture can be after a pattern `((NOUN)some text here)`, and if it is not that pattern has to end if any of the elements of the list `list_limiting_elements` appear.

In this way, perform this restructuring of the input string so that it looks like this **output**, after using a `re.sub(, , capture_where_capsule, flags = re.IGNORECASE)`

```
"((PL_ADVB)alrededor ((NOUN)del auto rojizo, algo grande y completamente veloz)). Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro del baúl) rápidamente ((PL_ADVB)abajo de una caja) ((PL_ADVB)por sobre ello) vimos una caña."
```

Keep in mind that an adverb from the `list_limiting_elements` list represents the beginning of the capture, but if there is a second adverb within the captured text, then this will act as an end limit.

Comment: Let's try to break it down to smaller tasks:
1. replace words that appear in list_all_adverbs_of_place with `((PL_ADVB)the text)`:
This can be achieved with the following pattern and the re.sub function in python:
`(adentro|dentro|al rededor|alrededor|abajo|hacía|hacia|por sobre|sobre)`
The substitution string is: `(PL_ADVB)$1`

demo: https://regex101.com/r/QuNRDi/1

2. now we want to encapsulate the result of the first task + the rest of the string:
(re.sub again)
`((?:adentro|dentro|al rededor|alrededor|abajo|hacía|hacia|por sobre|sobre)[^.]+)\.
` sub with ((PL_ADVB)$1).

Comment: demo for 2 from my previous comment:
https://regex101.com/r/g5nmwg/1

Is this going in the right direction?

Comment: @O-O-O works relatively well, although for some reason it doesn't cut the capture when it encounters the word "rápidamente"